# Extension of a Set to Basis of Free Group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be free group on $\{x,y\}$. Consider the element $x^2$. Does there exists $z\in F$ such that $\{z,x^2\}$ generate whole $F$?

I thought in following direction. $x^2$ is not in commutator subgroup. If there is such a $z$ then $\{\overline{x}^2,\overline{z}\}$ will generate abelian group $F/[F,F]=\langle \overline{x}\rangle \oplus \langle \overline{y}\rangle$, but this is not possible, since from set $\{\overline{x}^2,\overline{z}\}$, we obtain only even powers of $\overline{x}$ in $F/[F,F]$. Is this correct?

More generally, given any $a=W(x,y)\in F$, what condition on $a$ guarantees that $\{a\}$ can be extended to a basis of $F$?

Comment: agree with your answer.

Comment: The answer is no. There is a general algorithm called the *Whitehead algorithm* for deciding whether a given subset of a free group extends to a free basis.

Comment: @Derek: if we follow the method of "bof" then we can decide it easily, isn't it? Say for example, $xy^2x$. By natural homomorphism from $\langle x,y\rangle$ to $\langle a,b\rangle\cong Z_2\times Z_2$, this element will go to identity, so it can not be extended to basis. Is Whitehead algorithm different from such technique?

Comment: I think the point is that there is a way to do the problem in more generality (is $w$ part of a free basis in $F_n$?), and Whiteheads algorithm "solves" it. Combinatorial Group Theory by Lyndon and Schupp is handy to have around (especially if this kind of stuff interests you). I am not sure if there is a connection between the two methods, there might be, but I don't see a way to extend bof's proof more generally (although I find his quite slick, although it should be "If $F$ were generated by $\{x^2,w\}$ for an arbitrary word $w$...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Klein four-group $V=\{1,a,b,c\}$ is generated by $\{a,b\}.$ Define a surjective homomorphism $h:F\to V$ with $h(x)=a$ and $h(y)=b.$ If $F$ were generated by $\{x^2,z\},$ then $V$ would be generated by $\{h(x^2),h(z)\}=\{1,h(z)\},$ so $V$ would be cyclic, which is absurd.